# Upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 on a Self Hosted Webserver problems

Tags: server, upgrade, apache2, php, webserver

Getting 404 errors when the upgrade is completed, I test the two websites (wordpress) on the Server and neither load - 404. The strange thing is I can pull up a page to show the PHP info and it says PHP 7.4. Apache is running.

I put the websites on a Hosted Server running 7.4 and they work fine.

I found when doing this upgrade it removes 7.2 so cant even roll back to that if thats the issue.

Currently running PHP 7.2.24. Before the upgrade. I ran dpkg -l | grep php | awk '{print $2}' | tr "\n" " "  to get a list of all the modules loaded.

After the upgrade I think I installed any missing PHP modules. Does the upgrade re-install the PHP modules as were before?

How do I work out whats not working correctly after the upgrade so I can try fix?

Are there any common things I should be doing when upgrade is completed?

Thanks.

Comment: "*doing this upgrade it removes 7.2*" The removal of old versions during a dist-upgrade/release-upgrade has been a basic characteristic of Debian-based systems for over 20 years. A properly-installed or properly-upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 should be running php 7.4, so "*Currently running PHP 7.2.24*" suggests that you have done some haywiring that you did not describe in your question.

Comment: Hi, I think you may have misread my question, 7.2 before upgrade, 7.4 after upgrade but the sites 404 on 7.4. As mentioned I have put the sites on another server running 7.4 and they work, just not on this server after upgrade. I understand, as I wrote i cant roll back to 7.2 after upgrade.

Comment: Right. That quote points out a clarification [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1347430/edit) that **you** should make in your question above. Comments are intended only to help you improve your question until it is answerable.

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (or the error log for the site if you've configured Apache to use a different file) that might point to the 404? Checking that Apache's `headers` and `rewrite` modules are still enabled would be another item to confirm.

Comment: Thanks Matigo. I will give the upgrade another go tonight and check the Apache error logs when the websites fail after the upgrade. I just grabbed a list of the installed apache modules as you suggested and will compare after upgrade to ensure rewrite and headers are enabled. Theres something small tripping the upgrade up.

Comment: Do I need to add ondrej/php after the upgrade ?